# Некорректно работает пагинация Django

Tags: django, pagination

Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

views.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(products, 3)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,
                'products/list.html',
                {'category': category,
                'categories': categories,
                'products': products,
                'page': page})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls', namespace = 'index'), name = 'index'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace = 'products'), name = 'products')
]
```

работают и категории и пагинация, но когда выбрана какая-то категория, все равно показываются все товары, даже не из этой категории

Comment: Где ваши урлы из `products.url`?

Answer (score 0):

У вас `paginator` создаётся из queryset до того как в нём появляется фильтрация.

Переставьте строку `paginator = Paginator(products, 3)` после блока `if category_slug`

Итого:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    paginator = Paginator(products, 3)

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,
                'products/list.html',
                {'category': category,
                'categories': categories,
                'products': products,
                'page': page})
```